# How to paste list of values into cells of same columns based on equal intervals in excel?

Tags: excel

Like i have list of some numbers and i wanted to paste those values in cells such as A1 which get first value then A9 get second value similary.
I want solution of this without using macros.

```
     A  B   C
1           
2           
3           
4           
5           
6           
7           
8           
9           
10          
11          
12          
13          
14          
15          
16          
17          
18
```

The value which I have are:-

```
87
75
67
74
94
99

98
80
64
65
59
77
97
99
```

so I wanted that value 87 goes to A1 then 75 goes to A9 then 67 goes to A18 and so on..

Comment: show the list references and where you want it every 9th row for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start in B1: =A1 just for the first (your list is in A1:A14 for example)
In B2 write the following:
`=IF(MOD(ROW(),9)=0,INDEX($A$1:$A$14,INT(ROW()/9)+1,1),"")`
Mod(Row(),9)=0 to test if the row is the 9th after the precedent Value
Int(Row()/9) to get from the list in A the next row
IF to return empty
You can drag it down
When finish copy column B paste special Values in a new column and you can work with it normally